# How to create consistent horizontal spacing?

Tags: texpad, macos

I want to create spacing like this.

[image: hspace]

But using hspace produce something like this.

[image: what I want]

minimal code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent Nama \hspace{10mm}: ... \\
NIS \hspace{10mm}: ... \\
Judul \hspace{10mm}: ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a tabular, minipages or parboxes or something similar.

Comment: Please post your code. You could also use a list, though a `tabular` is probably easier.

Comment: added minimal code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ways (untested, but should work):

No. 1:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{10cm}}
  Nama: & \dotfill\\
  NIS: & \dotfill\\
  Judul: & \dotfill
\end{tabular}
```

No. 2:

```
\parbox{3cm}{Nama:}\dotfill\\
\parbox{3cm}{NIS:}\dotfill\\
\parbox{3cm}{Judul:}\dotfill
```

No. 3:

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm}Nama:\end{minipage}\dotfill
\begin{minipage}{3cm}NIS:\end{minipage}\dotfill
\begin{minipage}{3cm}Judul:\end{minipage}\dotfill
```

No. 4 (requires `enumitem`):

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargin+3cm,labelwidth=3cm]
\item[Nama:] \dotfill
\item[NIS:] \dotfill
\item[Judul:] \dotfill
\end{itemize}
```

No. 5 (credits to egreg):

```
\makebox[3cm][l]{Nama:}\dotfill
\makebox[3cm][l]{NIS:}\dotfill
\makebox[3cm][l]{Judul:}\dotfill
```

Comment: What about `\makebox[3cm][l]{Nama:}`? Much better (and easier) than a `\parbox`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I easily forget the easy ones.

Comment: what is the closest that similar to tab key in microsoft word that handle automatically?

Comment: @abdulqoyyim The most similar to a tab key would be using the `tabbing` environment, but that's uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below:

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad:\,}l}
Nama & ... \\[6pt]
NIS & ... \\[6pt]
Judul & ... \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, with a customised `description` environment?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}%

\begin{description}[labelwidth =25mm,labelsep = 0pt, font=\sffamily]
  \item[Nama] : \dotfill

\item[NIS]: \dotfill

\item[Judul]: \dotfill
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

[image]